# Elasticsearch not getting all documents from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

Logstash version 8.6.0
Elasticcsearch version 7.17.8

The total number of documents that should be created in Elasticsearch is 28000

The steps I tried 10 times:

1. Remove index in elasticsearch
2. Start logstash
3. Wait until it finished in the logs. [2023-03-31T10:21:56,427][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][index] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"index"}. No Errors or Warning in the logstash logs.
4. Check kibana that there are 28000 docucments.
5. Check elasticsearch logs. No errors or warning there either.

- Twice the index has all 28000 documents.
- Four times the index had 4002 documents. Even after waiting 4h.
- Four times the index had 27713 docucments.

I have dead_letter_queue.enable: true but its empty.

What I can see from Retry Policy is:
400 and 404 errors are sent to the dead letter queue (DLQ), if enabled. If a DLQ is not enabled, a log message will be emitted, and the event will be dropped. See DLQ Policy for more info.
409 errors (conflict) are logged as a warning and dropped.

Which makes me believe that I dont have 400,404 or 409 errors. Since i dont get anything in the DLQ or warnings in the logs.

Is there a way to see if it has been sent to elasticsearch or that elasticsearch is dropping the documents?

From logstash logs it seems like logstash has sent all documents to elasticsearch.

```
...
[2023-03-31T10:21:55,645][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][index][d9299291c383ba4e70e5116a1b01ba758087b0cff45119233811238f41d0be0d] (0.006227s) SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
       *,
       'PERSON' + CAST(PERSON.Id AS VARCHAR(20)) AS uniqueid
       FROM PERSON) AS [T1] ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 14000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
[2023-03-31T10:21:56,427][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][index] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"index"}
```

```
input {
   jdbc {
       jdbc_connection_string => "#connectionstring"
       jdbc_user => "#username"
       jdbc_password => "#password"
       jdbc_driver_library => "./logstash-core/lib/jars/mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre18.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
       clean_run => true
       record_last_run => false
       jdbc_paging_enabled => true
       jdbc_page_size => 1000
       jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
       statement => "
       SELECT
       *,
       'PERSON' + CAST(PERSON.Id AS VARCHAR(20)) AS uniqueid
       FROM PERSON"
   }
   jdbc {
       jdbc_connection_string => "#connectionstring"
       jdbc_user => "#username"
       jdbc_password => "#password"
       jdbc_driver_library => "./logstash-core/lib/jars/mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre18.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
       clean_run => true
       record_last_run => false
       jdbc_paging_enabled => true
       jdbc_page_size => 1000
       jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
       statement => "
       SELECT
       *,
       'INVOICE' + CAST(INVOICE.Id AS VARCHAR(20)) AS uniqueid
       FROM INVOICE"
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["#elasticsearchurl"]
       index => "#elasticindex"
       action => "index"
       document_id => "%{uniqueid}"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Logstash [node stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#event-stats) APIs to understand where is the problem.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/events?pretty'
```

output

```
{
  "events" : {
    "in" : 28000,
    "filtered" : 28000,
    "out" : 28000,
    "duration_in_millis" : 2324391,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 343816
  }
```

check `events.in` and `events.out` and make sure there are **28000** documents. If not the data can be dropped during the filter part.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I set the logstash.yml api.http.host: "0.0.0.0"
But couldnt connect to logstash
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://localhost:9600/_node/stats/events?pretty -Method Get
Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: Interesting, on the first try it filters almost double the amount but the correct number of document are presented in elasticsearcch
```
"events" : {
    "in" : 28071,
    "filtered" : 53140,
    "out" : 53140,
    "duration_in_millis" : 27416,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 1233
  }
```
Second try:
```
"events" : {
    "in" : 28071,
    "filtered" : 4000,
    "out" : 4000,
    "duration_in_millis" : 11047,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 3763
  }
```

Comment: You are in the right way, go ahead :)